# Google Autocomplete "city" is missing but shown in autocomplete form input

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a weird problem when dealing with Google Maps Autocomplete / Places API, it autocompletes the given address just fine:

Street Streetnumber, City, Country = Römerstraße 101, Reith bei Seefeld, Österreich

[image]

With the autocompleted value, I am trying to get the address_component data.

```js
const autocomplete = new this.api.places.Autocomplete(
        options.input,
        {types: ['address'], sessiontoken: sessionToken}
        ),
        inputObj = $(options.input);
            
        inputObj.prop('placeholder', inputObj.data('geocode-autocomplete-placeholder'));
            autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
                try {
                    callback(options, {'queryResult': {'res': [autocomplete.getPlace()]}}, this);
                } catch (e) {
                    this.disableGeocoding();
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
```

Problem is with the returned result, where "city" is missing:

[image]

I would expect every information that has been autocompleted to be in the "address_components" data.

Questions:

1. Why is city missing, and not found in another node, although autocompleted?
2. How can/should i get the city information?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the names you posted, what would you expect the city to be? I assume Reith bei Seefeld. Can you post the code snippet you are using?

Comment: Thank you for tryingto help. I thought its more like a general problem, that autocomplete information is there and fully autocompleted in the form input but not returned in the results when doint autocomplete.getPlace()

Comment: What is the place ID of the prediction you select? When I enter this information I get a place with a type of route. For a route, you may not get a city in your response.

Comment: the place id of the chosen prediction "Römerstraße 101, Reith bei Seefeld, Österreich" is: EhxSw7ZtZXJzdHJhw59lLCA2MTAzLCBBdXN0cmlhIi4qLAoUChIJD1ZwJlQRnUcRcLKCJtYHpHESFAoSCVM2qRJZEZ1HESev9Y8vAthV

Comment: I think you've found a bug. If you go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete and click on Addresses you can get an autocomplete for this. However, the place ID that comes up (which you wrote above) is for a type of "route" when Geocoded (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=EhxSw7ZtZXJzdHJhw59lLCA2MTAzLCBBdXN0cmlhIi4qLAoUChIJD1ZwJlQRnUcRcLKCJtYHpHESFAoSCVM2qRJZEZ1HESev9Y8vAthV&key=YOUR_KEY). There is a mismatch somewhere in Google's database in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

According to these two links,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

It says *locality* of response is represents the *city* part of the address.

[image]

So you can see *locality* part in the response.

[image]

Refer those links to get more information.